# Zoomed screen with any other iPhone simulator other than iPhone 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

I am trying to test and refine the application I've been working on lately and I found that it looks as it should with the iPhone 11 simulator, but with any other iPhone (smaller/bigger screen) it seems to zoom the screen even if every item from the ContentView has a Leading/Trailing constraint to Superview = 20. It's zooming right until the appearance of the items and right until their horizontal end (labels, textfields, ...).

It seems to zoom, not cut, because besides the up-down scroll bar, now I am able to scroll left-right.

Here is the stack of the embedded views of the UIViewController with their constraints.[image]

The constraints for ContentView are Bottom to Superview = -70 / Top to Superview = 0 / Leading and Trailing to Superview = 0.

Xcode version used: 13.4.1

Comment: You should constrain your `ContentView` top/leading/trailing/bottom to the scroll view's `Content Layout Guide`... and constrain its width to the scroll view's `Frame Layout Guide`. Right now, I'm assuming the content view's subviews are determining its width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DonMag's [solution in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72690598/zoomed-screen-with-any-other-iphone-simulator-other-than-iphone-11/72704619#comment128402236_72690598) worked for me:

> You should constrain your `ContentView` top/leading/trailing/bottom to the scroll view's `Content Layout Guide`... and constrain its width to the scroll view's `Frame Layout Guide`. Right now, I'm assuming the content view's subviews are determining its width.